# Displaying array contents on page with a loop in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have several strings I want to display in a div, but they should fade in/out and be replaced with the next string in the array looping back to the first.

Cork from #jquery on freenode IRC suggested I use .queue but it doesn't seem to be working. Nothing appears.

Where have I gone wrong here?

This code was based on [the last example on jquery's .queue page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/)

```
<div class="introText"></div>

<script>
    /*
        Fade each above string in and out as content for the div sequentially
        in a loop
    */
    var Messages = [
        "Matured Dieting via Smartphone",
        "The Academic IQHE Diet",
        "For only R 400.00 / year",
        "Follow this super diet on mobile",
        "<a href=\"http://www.m.smartpeeps.co.za\">m.smartpeeps.co.za</a>"
    ];

    function IntroText() {
        var i = 0;
        var Div = $(".introText");

        // div text should start with Messages[0] and loop to
        // Messages[4], the restart at Messages[0] 
        $.each(Messages, function() {
            // hide the previously shown item
            if (i == 0) {
                if (i >= 4) {
                    $.queue(Div[0], "fx", function() {
                        $(this).hide("slow");
                        $.dequeue(this);
                    });
                } else {
                    $.queue(Div[0], "fx", function() {
                        $(this).html(Messages[i - 1]).hide("slow");
                        $.dequeue(this);
                    });
                }

                // display the new item
                $.queue(Div[0], "fx", function() {
                    $(this).html(Messages[i]).show("slow");
                    i = i++;
                    $.dequeue(this);
                });
            } else {
                // loop back and display the first item again
                $.queue(Div[0], "fx", function() {
                    i = 0;
                    $(this).html(Messages[i]).show("slow");
                    $.dequeue(this);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    // run it
    IntroText();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is use a `setInterval()` for make a proper loop. Show and hide content with `fadein()` / `fadeOut()`and with **modulo** `%` you can check when the count must be restart. `startMessage` allow you to start loop message since any of item.

```js
/*
        Fade each above string in and out as content for the div sequentially
        in a loop
    */
    var Messages = [
        "Matured Dieting via Smartphone",
        "The Academic IQHE Diet",
        "For only R 400.00 / year",
        "Follow this super diet on mobile",
        "<a href=\"http://www.m.smartpeeps.co.za\">m.smartpeeps.co.za</a>"
    ];
    

   
    function IntroText() {
        var Div = $(".introText")
        var startMessage = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
          Div.html(Messages[startMessage]).fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
          startMessage++;
          if(startMessage % Messages.length == 0){
            startMessage=0;
          }
        },2000)
    }

    // run it
    IntroText();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="introText" style="display:none"></div>
```