# Loop through messages in sequence with a pause in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm putting together an extremely basic script to display messages in a non-profit's reception - all it has to do is iterate through a list of messages, displaying each one for 11 seconds and fade them in and out.

So basically:

*message fades in*

Welcome! Will be with you shortly

*11 second pause*

*message fades out*

*message fades in*

Keep watching this screen for our latest news and initiatives

*11 second pause*

*message fades out*

an so on and so forth. What I have at the moment is this (plagiarised from [Displaying array contents on page with a loop in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065673/displaying-array-contents-on-page-with-a-loop-in-jquery)):

```
var Messages = [
    "TEST 1",
    "TEST 2",
    "TEST 3",
    "TEST 4",
];

function DisplayMessages() {

    var Div = $("#content");

    var startMessage = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        
        Div.html(Messages[startMessage]).fadeIn().delay(11000).fadeOut();

        startMessage++;

        if(startMessage % Messages.length == 0) {
            startMessage    =   0;
        }
    }, 11000)
}

// run it
DisplayMessages();
</script>
```

Embarrassingly enough I can't figure out how to fix the timing so that each message fades in and out and displays for 11 seconds in-between. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your interval runs every 11 seconds. In addition to every 11 seconds you are delaying the faceOut by 11 seconds. You need to start with an Element, start your Interval and fadeOut the previous item and fadeIn the next one within your Interval

Answer (score 0):

You have a function running at an interval of 11 seconds. What needs to be done inside this function is:

- First `fadeOut` the current text
- Wait for the `fadeOut` animation to complete
- Replace the text
- `fadeIn` the new text

However, just place the first text in the div before starting the interval timer

```js
var Messages = [
  "TEST 1",
  "TEST 2",
  "TEST 3",
  "TEST 4",
];

function displayMessages() {
  var TIMER_INTERVAL = 11000;
  var FADE_INTERVAL = 500;

  var $div = $("#content");
  $div.text(Messages[0]);

  var messageCounter = 1;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (messageCounter === Messages.length) {
      messageCounter = 0;
    }
    $div.fadeOut(FADE_INTERVAL, function() {
      $div.text(Messages[messageCounter]);
      $div.fadeIn(FADE_INTERVAL);
      messageCounter++;
    });

  }, TIMER_INTERVAL)
}
displayMessages();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Prakhar, this works great on my PC, thank you - can I ask why it doesn't work on the device they're using to display the messages? The useragent is "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/73.0.3683.103 safari/537.36" if that helps at all?

Comment: I have replaced `let` and `const` with `var`. Try runnning it now. If it does not work then check if that device is connected to internet, because this script downloads jQuery. Without it, an error will be thrown.

Comment: Hmmmm it doesn't seem to cycle through the messages and stays on Test 1

Comment: Can you access the console of that device and check if there is an error

Comment: I can't unfortunately, but it's doing the same on my PC and nothing in the console at all..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Messages = [
    "TEST 1",
    "TEST 2",
    "TEST 3",
    "TEST 4",
];

(function DisplayMessages() {
    var startMessage = 0; 
    displayMessage(Messages[startMessage]); // Display instantly for the first time 
    
    // After some interval 
    setInterval(() => {
      ++startMessage;
      if(startMessage %  Messages.length == 0) {
        startMessage = 0;
      }
      displayMessage(Messages[startMessage]);
    }, 4000);
})();

function displayMessage(message) {
    var Div = $("#content");
    Div.html(message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
}

// run it
// DisplayMessages();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Priyadarshi, this also works perfectly on my PC, but has the same effect as Prakhar's where it doesn't display on the other screen.